# should I add a sha256 signature to an AES_256_CBC encrypted token?

Tags: encryption, hmac, sha256, token

currently I generate a token for an mobile app the way below. I decrypt the token to process the request and assess the user is logged in. I'm on TLS RSA 2048 bits connection. I was wondering if $GLOBALS is safe and if adding an hmac_sha256 would make my token harder to forge or it wouldn't change much.

```
$GLOBALS['encryption_key'] = <<<'EOT'
 MIGsAgEAAiEAwtvvzQzXiesVUPxXV7+jvUbmXfavBqxdakC1Tn+PpmcCAwEAAQIg
 WtklzWkOWKv0zURJCI09riGVIPIzGx1XPmFVaAbOeBECEQDynUX9BuIv3k6IA1wm
 IcSpAhEAzZwpEHQtbj3xpiWy34/sjwIRAJ2ltmmxBF6obI0S6djZTmkCEQDLpv5h
 hsEs7Xv5lmOK3lJvAhEAxJzS4NEgH2fF7mfaLfIWWg==
 EOT;

function new_auth_token($user) {
  $token_data = [
      'param1'   => 'type',
      'param2'   => $user['p2'],
      'param3'   => $user['p3'],
      'param4'   => $user['p4'],
      'param5'   => $user['p5'],
      'expedite' => (time() + (3600*24*180))
  ];
  $json  = json_encode($token_data);
  $iv    = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length(AES_256_CBC));
  $ssl   = openssl_encrypt($json, AES_256_CBC, $GLOBALS['encryption_key'], 0, $iv);
  $token = base64_encode($ssl).'.'.base64_encode($iv);
  return $token;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must authenticate the ciphertext because the encryption is malleable. The best way is to use an AEAD. If you can't do that, you should use hmac-sha256 with a key that must remain secret but must be different from the AES key. You must MAC the IV and the ciphertext after you encrypt and store the result in the token (like you store the IV). You must check the MAC before trying to decrypt the ciphertext. You must use a constant time comparison function to verify the MAC.

Otherwise people can decrypt messages, fake messages, maybe extract the AES key.

Notice all the "musts"? It's easy to mess it up. You should prefer a higher level api that does it right and does not allow you to do it wrong. Try libsodium.

EDIT

Notes about your code:

Your AES "encryption key" is an RSA private key. You do know that RSA keys are not AES keys, right? Also, 256 bit RSA is completely useless, broken in minutes on a laptop. BTW, now that you've published the RSA key, you can't use it for anything real, even if it used to be a strong key (RSA keys with modulus of 2048 bits and up are secure).

AES-256 keys are byte arrays of length 32 bytes. In base64 that would be 45 bytes. You need to decode the base64 before you use the string in encryption or decryption. You can generate strong AES keys like so: `head -c32 /dev/urandom | base64`.

You should use a library with an API that would not let you pass a string with supposed AES key that is of the wrong length.

In conclusion, you should read a lot more about crypto before you try to use it with someone's sensitive information.

Comment: Well, you told me I should add a hash on the cypher using a secret key( or salt) to hash the cypher and iv and append that to the token and check first the hash before deciphering. This is indeed what i'm hesitating to do my question thus: is the hash harder to brute force than the AES?

Comment: The secret key for the MAC is not a salt. The important part with HMAC is not that it's a hash but that it's a MAC. You can use other MACs like CBC-MAC, GMAC or Poly1305 and they would work just as well and they are not hashes at all. To brute-force AES-256, you need to try 2^256 keys. To brute-force a HMAC-SHA-256 authentication tag, you need to try 2^256 tags. Both are impossible to do, so in practice they are equally strong. To get a mathematical answer about best known attack on both and which is harder to perform using plausible hardware, you should ask on crypto stackexchange.

Comment: Indeed I did not know that there could be such difference between a random string and another (RSA key and AES key). I though 256 bit was 1792 bit short but the token would get so long... btw indeed the published key is a fake one for the purpose of this post. thank for the head -c32 /dev/urandom | base64 i am looking into it.

Comment: How did you know it was an RSA key? I indeed generated it using openssl genres 256. Is it because of the padding = at the end?

Comment: And of course, there is no sensitive information for now and in a near future.

Comment: The RSA key is not random bits, it's encoded using ASN.1 DER and I recognized that in the base64 encoded form.

Answer (score 0):

Push the sha hash of your token to the client and register the token in a session or other persistent memory storage mechanism.

Each request the client would push the sha hash of the token back to the server at which time the corresponding encrypted token could be hashed, revalidated, decrypted and verified for permissions etc.

That would be the easiest I terms of development time etc.

Depending on the level of security you wish to implement the other posters response regarding digital signatures and/or hmac of the token is another route.

You really should scrap all of it and research existing solutions such as oAuth (I would recommend version 1 of the spec if you're dead set on utilizing cryptographic primitives).

Comment: I've implemented the hash in my token since yesterday. I've looked into jwt oAuth i've redesigned since your answers.

Comment: Message Authentication Codes are not digital signatures. A simple hash instead of a MAC can only work if you can regenerate the exact payload again to hash it, but you usually can't. Also note his json serialization is not deterministic.